# How to check if user got redirected to new page in Serenity

Tags: serenity-bdd

I started playing around with Serenity BDD and the screenplay pattern in Java. While I get the basic idea I have some trouble with applying the key concepts. Here is what I'd like to do...

My first attempt is to automate the login of a user into the application. This consists of the following:

1. Open a specific URL.
2. Enter user credentials and hit the submit button.
3. Check that the user is on the "Welcome page".

I successfully implemented items 1 and 2 but I'm struggling with the check at 3.

#### The JUnit Test

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToLogin() {
    user.whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.with(browser));
    user.wasAbleTo(OpenTheApplication.onTheLoginPage());
    user.attemptsTo(SubmitUserCredentials.withValues("test", "test"));
    user.should(???);
}
```

After having submitted the credentials the user gets redirected to the welcome page. The `???` shall indicate that I don't have a solid idea how to implement this check.

1. Check that the new URL matches that of the welcome page.
2. Check that a certain text is visible on the welcome page.
3. Check that a certain element is visible on the welcome page.

I know that I would need to implement some class of `Question` but that's it. Could you provide me with some hint how you would do that?

Answer (score 2):

In the Serenity BDD you can write a Question class that:

import static net.thucydides.core.webdriver.ThucydidesWebDriverSupport.getDriver;

implements Question < Boolean >

in it would be the method:

```
@Override
public Boolean answeredBy(Actor actor) {
```

and in it you can:

```
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

and in my case I had a loop to do few more checks in case the URL gets changed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, [serenity-ensure](https://johnfergusonsmart.com/serenity-ensure-fluent-assertions-in-serenity-screenplay/) could help

```
Ensure.thatTheCurrentPage().currentUrl()
```

return URL as StringEnsure that we can use build-in String method like equals, contains.. to check.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use waitForTextToAppear() method or waitFor(xpath)  method to verify welcome page